# Need help shortening this query by either using a type of "for" or "while" loop

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if there is any way in which I can alter this SQL query so that I don't have to perform the UNION every time for a new field ("FieldName") from which I have to extract data.

I have about 30 fields with the name "Waybill1 up to "Waybill30".

I would like to perform the below query without having to use the UNION for every single field ID.

Here is the query, using only 3 of the "FieldName" values:

```
SELECT `FieldValue`, `SubmissionID` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = "Waybill1" AND `FieldValue` != ""
UNION
SELECT `FieldValue`, `SubmissionID` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = "Waybill2" AND `FieldValue` != ""
UNION
SELECT `FieldValue`, `SubmissionID` FROM `jos_rsform_submission_values` WHERE `FieldName` = "Waybill3" AND `FieldValue` != "" ORDER BY `SubmissionId` ASC
```

It should basically perform the same task as a "for" loop in PHP/Javascript etc.

I am not that familiar with SQL, so any help/guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `UNION` here, you can just use the [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator

The `IN` operator allows you to specify multiple values in a `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT FieldValue,
       SubmissionID
FROM   jos_rsform_submission_values
WHERE  FieldName IN ('Waybill1', 'Waybill2', 'Waybill3', 'Waybill4', etc...)
   AND FieldValue != ""
ORDER BY SubmissionId ASC
```

Comment: Thank you so much @DNKROZ! I really appreciate it, what an easy solution!

Comment: No problem, glad to help!